# Getting validation issues because of image_picker_ios for my flutter app after uploading to App Store. I'm using Xcode 15 beta on macOS sanoma

Tags: ios, flutter, plugins, app-store, publish

Below is the mail I have received from App Store team.

*Dear Developer,
We identified one or more issues with a recent delivery for your app, "App-Name" 3.1.5 (3106). Please correct the following issues, then upload again.
ITMS-90338: Non-public API usage - The app links to non-public libraries in Frameworks/image_picker_ios.framework/image_picker_ios: /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AVFCapture.framework/AVFCapture, /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AVFCore.framework/AVFCore. If method names in your source code match the private Apple APIs listed above, altering your method names will help prevent this app from being flagged in future submissions. In addition, note that one or more of the above APIs may be located in a static library that was included with your app. If so, they must be removed. For further information, visit the Technical Support Information at http://developer.apple.com/support/technical/
Best regards,
The App Store Team*

Tried clean build and even tried installing pods again.

Comment: You can't upload using beta tools. You need to use thenreleased version of Xcode

Comment: Are you telling me that there is no way to publish an app using macOS sanoma currently? On sanoma only beta Xcode works as of now. So there is no way to publish using beta Xcode? Are you sure about this?

Comment: Yes. This has always been the case. You cannot use beta tools to submit apps to the App Store. If you can't run Xcode 14.2 on Sonoma then you will need to reinstall macOS Ventura. You won't be able to use Xcode 15 until the GM is released.